# Subsetting data frame in R after reading in data with scan

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm reading in data about an HTTP access log. I've got a file with columns for the ip address, year, month, day, hour and requested URL. I read the file in like this:

```
ipdata = scan(file="sample_r.log", what=list(ip="", year=0, month=0, day=0, hour=0, verb="", url=""))
```

This seems to work. R-Studio says that ipdata is a list[7] and "names(ipdata)" returns

```
[1] "ip"    "year"  "month" "day"   "hour"  "verb"  "url"
```

So that seems cool. I wanted to do something fun, like graph some data for a specific hour. I tried doing a subset:

```
s <- subset(ipdata, ipdata$hour==3)
```

This data looks remarkably different than the first data frame. s is a list[297275] and the following doesn't work right:

```
> table(ipdata$verb)

GET    POST 
2870709 1596748 

> table(s$verb)
character(0)
```

Am I going about this the correct way? What I typically do is wrap my data frame in a table() and then barplot or dotplot it. Is R a good way to do this? I want to say "Show me all of the top URLs in hour 3", for example. Or "How many times did this IP address show up per hour?"

**Update** It looks like by using `read.table` instead of `scan` I was able to get a data frame. Apparently scan returns a list of lists or something? Definitely confusing to a n00b like myself but I'm feeling good about it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ran

```
dat <- as.data.frame(ipdata)
str(dat)
```

.... you would probably see that it was pretty much the same as the results of your read.table() operation. `read.table` is a wrapper for `scan` and does a lot of formatting and consistency checking.

Comment: Ah! Does `read.table` essentially do a "as.data.frame" when it's done?

Comment: Well, `read.table` assigns "data.frame" as the class of its returned  object. It does a lot of checking of names and lengths and classes before it assigns the class. Just type `read.table` at your console. In addition to seeing the amount of consistency enforcement, you will get an appreciation for why it is sometimes slow.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. I'm still getting used to R and R Studio and just this morning learned about the help feature :)